# I need help with a command block chain

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Ok here's my dilemma. I am trying to build a command block creation that triggers 5 repeating command blocks using the `/setblock redstone_block` then `/setblock air`.  I can get the repeating to work and the second chain which is `/setblock ~ ~ ~2` air but it's so fast it over rides the previous chain block which is `/setblock ~ ~ ~3 redstone_block`.

How do I get it so the redstone block is placed for 1.5 seconds and then gets replaced by an air block and will it be tileable? Current progress:

[image]

Comment: I would suggest adding more details to your question.  What are you trying to do with these blocks?  Does the redstone block have to be placed for 1.5 seconds or are you just trying to trigger something with it?  Do you need it to be tileable?

Comment: I'm trying to get the repeating command block to summon mobs 5 times and each activation should last 1.5 seconds. It will end up being a perfect amount to get from Lvl 0 to Lvl 30. I'm sorry I'm not the best at asking questions. It's hard to put into works what I mean.

Comment: What are you doing with it?  Creating some sort of xp grinder?  Is there some reason you aren't using 'xp 1395 @p' ?

Comment: It's going to be a mending machine come the next update that you pay a diamond block to use. It's for my realms server so I'm trying to make it as legit as I can. I want people to actually fight for the xp not just push a button and be given it. If that makes any sense.

Comment: Are you looking for a compact solution?  Is tileable required?  Is redstone acceptable to create a delay or are you wanting this to be mainly a command block solution?

Comment: As long as it's not thousands of blocks long I'm fine with it not being compact. Redstone is fine as a delay method as long as I can get each reapting command block to activate for 1.5 seconds. And as far as tileableity I'm flexible as Iong as the end goal is achieved:)

Comment: Why don't you just use a repeater?

Answer (score 1):

Since a redstone timer method is allowed, here's my solution.
[image: screenshot of redstone]

More information:

- The lever is the input. Replace it with your diamond block detector.
- The redstone lamp is the output. Replace it with your command block.
- All the repeaters are set to 4 ticks, apart from the one closest to the redstone lamp, which is set to 1 tick. This is required for the correct duration of 1.5 seconds.
- The piston is sticky.
- You can put any (moveable) block on top of it, it does not have to be stone.
- The screenshot is from Minecraft 1.11.2 PC/Linux (vanilla), although Pocket Edition should work exactly the same for this task.

It's probably possible to get the redstone much more compact than this, but I'm not too good at that.

EDIT: Spent about an hour compacting and writing instructions to re-create this 2x4x10 design:

[image: thinner design]

It's 2 blocks wide, but you'll need to leave a space in between if you want to tile these. I'm not going to keep trying for a tileable version with no gap, but I'm sure it's possible.